# Using robots.txt or 301 redirects to fix duplication errors

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, robots.txt

We're having an issue where Google thinks that /product.html is the same as /category/product.html. They are both the same content but two separate pages. I could manually

```
Redirect 301 /product1.html https://www.website.com/category/product1.html
Redirect 301 /product2.html https://www.website.com/category/product2.html
```

but we have thousands of products and new ones will be added continuously.

I want to know if there's a way of doing something like this:

```
Disallow: /*.html$
Allow: /*/*.html$
```

In the robots.txt file? Or if there's a way to do that in the .htaccess file using a 301 redirect. Or if there's a way in Opencart to automatically 301 the /product.html to the /category/product.html (the issue with this is that each product is in multiple categories).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here two things you can do :

**In your .htaccess**

A generic 301 redirection

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

**In your HTML template**

Add the following in the  of your product template. This will help Google to know which is the right page when there is duplicate content.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com/product1.html" />
```

Google doesn't recommend the use of robots.txt for this purpose :

> While we encourage you to use any of these methods, none of them are
>   required. If you don't indicate a canonical URL, we'll identify what
>   we think is the best version or URL.
>
> Don't use the robots.txt file for canonicalization purposes. Don't use
>   the URL removal tool for canonicalization: it removes all versions of
>   a URL from search. Don't specify different URLs as canonical for the
>   same page (e.g. one URL in a sitemap and a different URL for that same
>   page using rel="canonical").

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2

---

According to your comment, this is the rule to redirect example.com/ *.html to example.com/category/ *.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+.html)$ category/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Canonicals are pretty much a no go for us, we've tried setting them up but can't get them to work correctly. Opencart creates multiple variations of the same page (e.g if you type in example.com/randomletters/product.html it wont 404 but it will create that page at that url) but would keep the canonical tag for all of them; making the canonical tag useless. So what exactly does that 301 redirection do? Does it redirect category/*? We're looking to redirect example.com/*.html to example.com/category/*.html

Comment: I've understood the opposite. Check my edit, I've added a rewriterule to match your need

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That adds the product.html page to category/ correct? But all these product.html pages are in different categories. I don't think I'm able to do this with a 301 unless I do each product separately

Comment: Yes, you can't add the category in the redirection if you haven't it in the original URL.